# Is there any use of registering my config server in Eureka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm specifying the config server URI `spring.cloud.config.uri` in the `bootstrap.properties` file of all my config server clients.

So is there any use of adding an `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation to it, and registering the configuration service in Eureka?

Answer (score 5):

There are various use cases why registering your config server on Eureka could be useful:

#### Discovery-first bootstrapping

When using the Spring cloud config service, you have two choices when bootstrapping your application, as mentioned by [the documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/1.4.x/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_spring_cloud_config_client):

1. Using a config-first setup (default)
2. Using a discovery-first setup

When you use a discovery-first setup, all applications can retrieve their configuration by looking up the URL of the configuration service on Eureka:

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config-service
```

In this case, the application will look for a service named `config-service` on Eureka, and will use the given hostname and port to connect.

---

#### Discoverability

Some tools, like Zuul, Spring boot admin, ... will automatically discover all applications and use them, for example:

- Spring boot admin can be setup to automatically discover all applications to manage them.
- Zuul will automatically forward all routes matching `/{application-name}/**` to the given application.

Answer (score 1):

[@EnableDiscoveryClient](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/EnableDiscoveryClient.html) activates the `Netflix Eureka` `DiscoveryClient` implementation and tells it to register itself with a service registry.

So, without this annotation, your application will not able to register itself to any Registry. And hence will not be discovered from any service as well.

---

**Edit**: Registering your application to `DiscoveryServer` provides many benefits, some of them are below :

- **Application independence**: When you register your application to DiscoveryServer it decouples it from another application. Doing so you don't need to hardcode the name and URL of your application in using application.
- **Load Balancing**:  Register your application to DiscoveryServer provides an effective and efficient way to provide load balancing.
- **Multiple instances of same application**: In order to provide load balancing you can add multiple instances of a single application.
- **Resilience**: When an instance is not working then Server can use the circuit breaker to handle requests effectively and helps in making system responsive and resilient.

Comment: But as I mentioned, I'm adding this spring.cloud.config.uri in bootstrap.properties file of all my clients that want to use the config-server. So is there any point in registering my config-server to Eureka? Will doing so be of any use in case I'm adding multiple config servers, and registering them to Eureka so I can balance the load between them, or add more just as a fault-tolerance measure?